# Why does my cross validation score get better after each iteration

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, boosting

I am building a regression task using XGboost in R. I noticed my cv score gets better as I increase my cv score, even as high as 100k. What could be resposible for this? I will like my model to converge.

**Below are my paramenters**

````
tune_grid <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = seq(from = 50, to = 50000, by = 50),#15k+
  eta = c(0.03),#0.021 final but could be improved further
  max_depth = c(4),#4
  gamma = c(0),#0.4 final
  colsample_bytree = c(0.6),# final
  min_child_weight = c(0),#final
  subsample = c(0.9)#0.85 final
)

tune_control <- caret::trainControl(
  method = "cv", # cross-validation
  number = 5, # with n folds
  #index = createFolds(tr_treated$Id_clean), # fix the folds
  verboseIter = FALSE, # no training log
  allowParallel = TRUE # FALSE for reproducible results

)

xgb_tune <- caret::train(
  x = input_x,
  y = input_y,
  trControl = tune_control,
  tuneGrid = tune_grid,
  method = "xgbTree",
  verbose = TRUE,
  metric="RMSE"
)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

"Noticed my cv score gets better as I increase my cv score" could you elaborate? If you mean as $n \rightarrow N$ where $n$ is the number of folds and $N$ is the number of samples, this is because you're getting closer to LOOCV.